# EFI and 2 recovery partitions on wrong drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

I have an SSD and an HDD. Windows is on the SSD but as you can see EFI and recovery partitions (there are two for some reason) are on the other drive. I'm not sure if it's always been like that but after dual booting with Ubuntu probably had something to do with it.

I've deleted the dual boot and everything is working fine but I'll probably go back to dual boot some time and I wanna make sure that things will work, so: should I leave everything as is, move the EFI partition to the SSD or format both drives and do a clean install?

Also, the SSD is MBR so if I formatted it I could also convert it to GPT, but is it worth the hassle?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The SSD is not large enough to need GPT, so it can stay as MBR.

You also have various Recovery partitions that probably accumulated when upgrading
Windows to a new version that needed more space for its recovery partition.
The largest is probably the latest and the others are superfluous,
but as they are quite small there is no reason to take the risk of
deleting the wrong one.

All in all, moving the EFI would not be simple and requires several advanced disk
editing, each with its own risk.

From my point of view, moving the partitions will not improve anything and
would be only a cosmetic change. I would keep everything as it is.
(Famous words: If it ain’t broke, don’t fix it.)